# How Yii2 outputs standard js

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

The description of the title may not be clear.
Or Yii2 solve this problem is not the idea.
The specific needs are like this -
Other sites need to reference a page of this site developed by Yii. This page needs to output the standard js. The output code example is as follows -

```
document.write('<a href="https://test.com/counter.php">test string</a>');
```

Other sites are quoted in the following ways -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/counter.php"></script>
```

Comment: I think that your problem is not related with **yii2**. You always can execute javascript in any place that you want. And also write links to other code sources as in your example.

Comment: This is not a Yii2  (Yii) question  ...  your question is not clear

Comment: not clear what you are asking. but `document.write` [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW; 
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
Yii::$app->response->data = "document.write('<a href=\"https://test.com/test.php\">test string</a>');";
return Yii::$app->response->send();
```